# How can I find IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware) code?

Tags: asp.net-core

Can I find the `IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)` implementation somewhere?

I didn't find this on GitHub.

Also I don't understand how this piece of code works:

[RunExtensions.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/RunExtensions.cs)

I would be grateful if someone could give me a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation is here [ApplicationBuilder](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs,b4301f7d54723f02).

**EDIT**

From the above link this is actual implementation.

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Adds the middleware to the application request pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="middleware">The middleware.</param>
        /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/> after the operation has completed.</returns>
        public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
        {
            _components.Add(middleware);
            _descriptions?.Add(CreateMiddlewareDescription(middleware));
     
            return this;
        }
```

The method  `app.Use(...)` in `RunExtensions.cs`  will call this Implementation above.

**Supplementary**

Explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> Middleware is software that's assembled into an app pipeline to handle
> requests and responses. Each component:
>
> Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the
> pipeline. Can perform work before and after the next component in the
> pipeline. Request delegates are used to build the request pipeline.
> The request delegates handle each HTTP request.
>
> Request delegates are configured using Run, Map, and Use extension
> methods.

The RunExtensions code is already explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

> Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request
> pipeline.

Both these methods as quoted above will add request delegates to the pipeline,the fundamental difference between [app.Use(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.useextensions.use?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [app.Run(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is that with `app.Use(...)` you can pass the request to the subsequent middleware in the pipeline where as with `app.Run(...)` the request delegate passed in this method is the final middleware that executes in that pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want the implementation of 
Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware),
 not the implementation of
IApplicationBuilder Use(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<HttpContext, RequestDelegate, Task> middleware).
About Run(this IApplicationBuilder app, RequestDelegate handler)
My question is actually about the presence of _ at the input of the method.
 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/RunExtensions.cs   In fact, I can't understand how a method input can be trivial.

Comment: @tara I have added the edit, the code in `RunExtensions.cs` will call the Use Implementation in [ApplicationBuilder](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs,b4301f7d54723f02)